# Помощь с простейшим калькулятором на C++. Ошибка: "[Error] ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c++

Сразу к делу - никак не могу понять, на что конкретно ругается компилятор Dev C++ в написанном мной коде. Ошибка расшифровывается на разных источниках по-разному, поэтому и пишу сюда дабы привести конкретно свой пример.

Собственно сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int_main()
{
    double a, c;
    char b;
    cout << "Enter the example: ";
    cin >> a, b, c;
    if (b == '+')
    {
        cout << a+c;
    }
    if (b == '-')
    {
        cout << a-c;
    }
    if (b == '*')
    {
        cout << a*c;
    }
    if (b == '/')
    {
        cout << a/c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке компиляции выскакивает ошибка:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o)    In function `main':
>
> C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c   undefined
>   reference to `WinMain'
>
> C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Projects\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit
>   status

Надеюсь на конструктивный и адекватный ответ с Вашей профессиональной точки зрения. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Что за, гм... недоразумение -

```
int_main()
```

??

У вас нет функции `main` в результате, вот компиляторы и возмущены. Второе сообщение говорит о том, что вы пытались собрать не консольное приложение, а оконное...

Сделайте `int main()` - скомпилируется.

Но не заработает. Хотя бы потому, что это -

```
cin >> a, b, c;
```

не чтение трех переменных.

Как именно читать

```
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

Но знаете, прочтите учебник по C++, начните с этого - у вас совершенно нет знаний...

Comment: Выдайте Страуструпа этому парню